# Как правильно в java реализовать словарь: "ключ" : "n-значений"?

Tags: java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно создать словарь, который будет записывать в ключ, по мере вхождения информации, значения в n количестве.

Comment: `Map<Key, List<Value>>`.

Comment: правильно юзать готовые решения, ибо изобретение своего велосипеда всегда черевато багами и нечитаемым кодом. посему берете гуаву и мультимеп вам в помощь: https://www.baeldung.com/guava-multimap

Answer (score 2):

Как указано в комментарии, достаточно использовать мапу, в которой для каждого ключа будет храниться коллекция значений (список `List` или множество `Set`):

```java
Map<K, List<V>> mapOfLists = new HashMap<>();
Map<K, Set<V>> mapOfSets = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

Для добавления в такую коллекцию можно использовать метод [`Map::computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-), в котором при необходимости будет создана новая коллекция значений для отсутствующего ключа, в которую сразу можно будет добавить значение:

```java
public static addValue(Key key, Value value) {
    mapOfLists.computeIfAbsent(key, (k) -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value);
    mapOfSets.computeIfAbsent(key, (k) -> new HashSet<>()).add(value);
}
```